# filterMatchMode lte and gte does not work on p:calendar in filter facet of p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, filter, datatable, calendar

I can not filter by table when I used Calendar in primeFaces.

[image]

JAVA:

```
private Date creationDate;
private Date dateFrom;
private Date dateTo;
```

XHTML (only working LT and GT / not working LTE, GTE):

```
<p:column filterBy="#{tab.dateTo}" headerText="Date to" filterMatchMode="lte">
            <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:calendar pattern="yyyy-MM-dd">
                    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" oncomplete="PF('datesTableDefinition').filter()"/>
                </p:calendar>
            </f:facet>
            <p:outputLabel value="#{tab.dateTo}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            </p:outputLabel>
        </p:column>
```

I would like to get == , < , >  ?

Comment: may be its all because of date comparison is time aware (including seconds)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, works for me!

Instead of  `filterMatchMode` use `filterFunction="#{controller.filterByDate}"`

```
public boolean filterByDate(Object value, Object filter, Locale locale) {
    if( filter == null ) {
        return true;
    }

    if( value == null ) {
        return false;
    }

    return DateUtils.truncatedEquals((Date) filter, (Date) value, Calendar.DATE);
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30116077/3255595